# Women without hijab is better than their hijab counterpart?

Tags: hijab

There is a challenging question in my Islamic textbook, that is which one is better: woman that doesn't wear hijab but her behavior is better or woman that wear hijab but her behavior is questionable (not good/worse)? Any answers?

Comment: This question is opinion based. There is no *acccurate* answer to the question, it is truly situation based. I bet it will get closed soon. You could rephrase yourself somehow though, and by that maybe draw conclusions. For instance, in situations like these, one first should look for the reason (sabab) for women to wear hijab. After that one may draw some logical conclusions.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "her behavior is questionable (not good/worse)"? Are you talking about committing major sins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the questionable behavior is against Islam's teaching (ruling), neither is better in the sense that both are doing something against Islam's teaching.

According to Quran Al-Baqarah: 208, we should enter Islam completely as each individual possibly could (Quran Al-Baqarah:286). Going from that, as long as they aren't engaging in polytheistic activities, both still have areas to learn and be better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to respond to your noteworthy/significant inquiry, I ought to remark that:

**Firstly, we should pay heed that each side has its positive and negative effects based on Allah's orders.**

**Secondly, I strongly believe that the root of such matters (I don't accuse all of them, but I assume many of them) can be archly/wicked,** what do I mean?

I mean, setting forth for such discussions (based on strict but feasible aspect) might be in order to strive to encourage less-insightful women to have less attention to the obligatory/significant issue of Hijab (hidden/indirect effect of such issues can be so! to pretend as if you can be a good person without Hijab...! But we must be very precise regarding such important matter.)

**Thirdly, it cannot comparable, since each of them are mandatory/significant in their positions**. For example, we cannot ask: Which of the following cellphone is better:

1: A cellphone which almost has every good programs such as: Camera, flashlight, ability of sending SMS, etc., but doesn't have internet explore (to use internet)

2: A cellphone which doesn't have camera, flashlight, the ability of sending SMS, etc., but it has internet.

**Consequently,** in practice/reality, we cannot easily recognize which one is better, since all of them are necessary/helpful from diverse angles, and each of them has its specific profitability/necessity. Hence, the very important issue/fact is that we ought to be so careful and don't be deceived of ...

---

**Update:**

But, if I compulsory have to choose one of them, based on my knowledge/perception:

Although not having nice behavior can be Haram or Makruh (it is better to abandon) and Islam have emphasis on having good behavior, but having hijab is an essential obligatory based on Islam and actually leaving it is considered as a haram act whose effect is equaled to having much torture in the hell ... (and even it can be the start of other sins, too)
Then, it can be concluded that being with hijab (even in that comparison) is seemed to be a priority than the other theory.

**Note:** presumably what I remarked could be more understandable/acceptable from the ones who follows Islam and have more obedience in comparison to the ones who occasionally take more attention to their own reasons rather than Allah/Islam orders/doctrine/concepts.

---

**Source:** [https://www.al-islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/hijab-muslim-womens-dress-islamic-or-cultural-sayyid-muhammad-rizvi/why-hijab)

Comment: So neither is better? Or wearing hijab and be a good person is the best?

Comment: I will complete my answer, in order to be more accurate for you. God bless you.

Comment: Could you add references about leaving hijab is "**(big)** haram" and "whose effect is equaled to having much torture in the hell". I understand that scholars say it is haram, but i think we need references about the grade (daraja) of the sin according to the scholars.

Comment: @Kilise In regards to sin, there are several views, I try to mention some of their more related:
From an aspect, it is said that, since the committing the sin (diverse sins) can be deemed as disobedience of Allah’s orders, then all of sins would be big sin, since in truth we have done sin/disobedience in a kind of Allah’s presence. Conclusion: all sins are great (big), but with diverse degrees (that some of them huger …)

Comment: From another aspect, I presume almost every/many Muslim know that wearing hijab is Wajib (in front of non-mahrams), so even from the view of logical: Whatever is wajib, it can be meant that if you don’t do that, subsequently you’ll get in trouble/torture, otherwise Allah would mention that it is Mustahab (recommended) to have hijab, whereas He mentions/orders it as a Wajib practice.

Comment: From another aspect, even we fairly evaluate the negative effect of being without hijab, we’ll even personally can perceive that it is a harmful/dangerous, since it can be the root of many other sins/troubles in the society and so on. (It, itself can have a vast research about its diverse disadvantages)
And eventually, from another (related/significant/informative) aspect, there

Comment: Some of ref. (in Farsi): 
 مفتاح الكرامة ج۵،ص۱۰۶۳
https://article.tebyan.net/179912/معنای-اصرار-بر-گناه-و-آثار-آن   .  .   
http://wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1_%D8%A8%D8%B1_%DA%AF%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%87_%D8%B5%D8%BA%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%87#foot5
            .    .  
https://article.tebyan.net/279330/%DA%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF%DB%8C-%D8%B9%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%B2%D9%86-%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AA-
کافی، ج 2، ص 282، بابُ الْإِصْرَارِ عَلَى الذَّنْبِ، حدیث 1

Comment: And finally, as a significant one: According to hadiths/Fiqh, it is said that when you have persistence/repetition on a minor sin, then it will be changed into a major sin. So, by that formula, I assume the one who is without hijab = She will repeat it again, won't?.      Good luck dear mate.